# What has happened to my anti-aliasing on text?

Tags: anti-aliasing, cleartype

I've been working from home for a few days and when remoted into my machine the text has been perfectly readable. Last week I did the same and had no issues at all, yet this week text on some sites is utterly unreadable:

[image: sample image from the register]

As you can see, the anti-aliasing seems to be turned off however I've gone through the cleartext setup and re-applied it with no change at all. Since I've remoted into this box previously and then used it afterwards I don't see why this time it's made all the text go strange? I'd prefer not to have to reboot if I can, as it's a pain.

Is there some way to make the anti-aliasing re-apply to the text other than running the cleartype setup?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed after working with email for awhile that it was ONLY text within the browser (chrome in this case) that was effected, and while not all sites, it didn't effect any other applications.

I quit chrome from the menu, and then made sure it was dead via the task manager, then restarted it (simply quitting and restarting wasn't working for some reason!). This has now cleared the issue.

The reason I guess I wasn't affected last week was chrome was started by the locally connected account, and then I remoted in afterwards, but this time I remoted in and started the applications all via the remote desktop connection and then logged in locally afterwards.